# Typescript Unsafe return of an `any` typed value

Tags: typescript, function, reusability

I am creating few date functions for my app and for date validation I am using [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/). All of the functions, I first convert them into string then I am formatting the date. Instead of writing same line every time(to convert them into string), I have decided to create a separate function for this. When add this function my format function, I am getting typescripts error: `Unsafe return of an` any `typed value`

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yg5xK.png)

```js
import { DateTime } from 'luxon'


const dateToStrings = (date: Date): string => DateTime.fromISO(new Date(date).toISOString())

export const formatDateMonthYear = (date: string | number | Date): string =>
  dateToStrings(date).toFormat(DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT)

export const formatTime = (date: string | number | Date): string =>
dateToStrings(date).toFormat(SHORT_TIME_FORMAT)

export const formatYearMonthDate = (date: string | number | Date): string =>
  DateTime.fromISO(new Date(date).toISOString()).toFormat(ISO_DATE_FORMAT)
```

Comment: How would you want this to work ? The `fromIso` method returns a `DateTime`  ?  And you trying to pass `string | number | Date` to your function that only accepts `Date`

Comment: Thank you for you quick response. What is the correct way I should do that?

Comment: Like this:  const dateToStrings = (date: string | number | Date): DateTime =>
  DateTime.fromISO(new Date(date).toISOString())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixing the types in your function should fix you issues :

```
const dateToStrings = (date: string | number | Date): DateTime =>
  DateTime.fromISO(new Date(date).toISOString());

export const formatDateMonthYear = (date: string | number | Date): string =>
  dateToStrings(date).toFormat(DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT);

export const formatTime = (date: string | number | Date): string =>
  dateToStrings(date).toFormat(SHORT_TIME_FORMAT);
```