# How to fetch with method GET And Type script

Tags: typescript, fetch

I'm true beginner with type script
can you help me with this simple fetch

this is function

```
export async function askForList(){
   return await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:3333/applist').then((res) => res.json()) 
}
```

this is expected data

```
interface RnMcharacter{ 
    id: number,
    img: string,
    name: string,
    number: number
};
```

I'v tried many combination but moast common error is
ERROR in src/transmission/apiserv.ts:27:4
@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return: Unsafe return of an `any` typed value.

Can you show me example of proper function so I can understad what mi doing wrong.
Thx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript Unsafe return of an \`any\` typed value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71030676/typescript-unsafe-return-of-an-any-typed-value)

Comment: You can add the type after the method name: `function askForList(): RnMcharacter {`

Answer (score 4):

You can type the `data` prop as `RnMcharacter`.
You can also remove the `then` call as you're using `async`|`await`

```
export async function askForList(){
  const res = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:3333/applist');
  const { data }: { data: RnMcharacter } = await res.json();
  return data;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it really helped me. I'v fixed one more bug in place where I call the function and now is grate.